# How do set the parameters of a single azure policy definition within an azure policy set definition using powershell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-policy

It's straightforward when adding parameters to a policy assignment which is done using a hash table in [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-9.2.0). However, in the case of a policy set definition, there are single definitions within a set that have their own parameters. Given the Microsoft documentation, where are the parameters entered [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azpolicysetdefinition?view=azps-9.2.0)?

**LINKS**

1. [Set an Azure Policy Assignment for a Policy Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azpolicyassignment?view=azps-9.2.0)
2. [Set an Azure Policy Set Definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/set-azpolicysetdefinition?view=azps-9.2.0)

Comment: What exactly the issue? Could you brief here?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new azure policy definition and tried setting up parameters using
`Set-AzPolicyDefinition` and it worked for me as expected.

To pass parameters, I created a `Json` file and added required parameters accordingly as shown below:

***eg.json (Parameter file):***

```json
{"allowedLocations": {
          "type":"Array",
           "metadata":
              {
                 "displayName": "Allowedlocations",
                  "description":"Thelistofallowedlocationsforresources.",
               },
                "allowedValues":["WestUs"]
      }
}
```

[image]

***Executed below command in Azure PowerShell:***

```
Set-AzPolicyDefinition -Name "<PolicyName>" -Parameter /home/xxxx/Myfile.json
```

[image]

***Values reflected in `Azure Portal -> Policy -> Defintions`:***

[image]